# Setting up firebase notifications

Tags: swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I've been working on setting up firebase notifications using cloud messaging and I've run into a problem. I've been following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/20201639-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-ios-push-notifications) tutorial, so if I did anything else wrong, which hopefully I didn't, please let me know. I've also been looking at [this](https://iosapptemplates.com/blog/ios-development/push-notifications-firebase-swift-5/) one.

Here's my AppDelegate code, which is the spot in which they told me to put all the stuff. I also did the certificate stuff, and hopefully, that works fine:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
      launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil
  ) -> Bool {
      
      FirebaseApp.configure()
      // 2
      FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
      
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      // 2
      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions) { _, _ in }
      // 3
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      
      Messaging.messaging().delegate = self //Here is one of the problems
    return true
  }
}
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
    @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void
  ) {
    completionHandler([[.banner, .sound]])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
  ) {
    completionHandler()
  }
}

func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
) {
  Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken //Here's the other problem
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
  func messaging(
    _ messaging: Messaging,
    didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?
  ) {
    let tokenDict = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
      name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
      object: nil,
      userInfo: tokenDict)
  }
}
```

The problem:

```
Type 'Messaging' has no member 'messaging'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay. I found the solution. Pretty simple actually. I accidentally had a swift view in my app named Messaging which was throwing off the syntax.

If you're having this problem. Make sure nothing in your project is named Messaging.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the old version of pods or dependencies.

```swift
FIRMessaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

Above code will work for you.

**Alternative**

If you are using pod you can updating with the following command.

```
pod update Firebase/Messaging
```

or just

```
pod update
```

Above command will update your all pods, be careful.

Comment: Now getting the error "'FIRMessaging' has been renamed to 'Messaging'" so that doesn't work. Let me try updating my pods.

Comment: Update: I updated the pods and still no luck.

Comment: When it says "'FIRMessaging' has been renamed to 'Messaging'", then use `Messaging`

Comment: I've already done that. That was in the original problem.